# Inherit a interface with template

Tags: c++, oop

I have class Interface Manager declare below:
In file Manager.h

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H
#include "../Datetime/Datetime.h"
template <class T>
class Manager{
    private:
    public:
        virtual void show() = 0;
        virtual void showByID(const string&) = 0;
        virtual T findByID(const string&) = 0;
        virtual int indexOf(const T) = 0;
        virtual int indexOf(const string&) = 0; 
        virtual void add(const T) = 0;
        virtual void remove(const T) = 0;
        virtual void removeByID(const string&) = 0;
        virtual void listByDate(const Date&) = 0;
};
#endif
```

Then I create a new class Client Manager inherit from class Manager
In file ClientManager.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_MANAGER_H
#define CLIENT_MANAGER_H
#include "../CTDL/LinkedList.h"
#include "../Manager.h"
#include "../Datetime/Datetime.h"
#include "../Client/Client.h"
class ClientManager: public Manager<Client> 
{
    private:
        LinkedList<Client> list;
    public:
        ClientManager();
        ~ClientManager();

        void show();
        void showByID(const string&);
        Client findByID(const string&);
        int indexOf(const Client);
        int indexOf(const string&);

};
#endif
```

I don't know is it possible to use template in Manager class?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? What value or advantages does your `Manager<T>` interface provide, exactly?

Comment: Well, a code like this can be made to compile, if that's what you are asking. Whether it can be made to meet your design goal is impossible to say, as you've never stated the aforementioned design goal.

Comment: *"I don't know is it possible to use template in `Manager` class?"* You actually use template in `Manager` class, and provided code is correct (assuming correct `#include`).*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.